# Hot reload a webapp and lib dependencies

Tags: webpack

I am developing a webapp that relies on 2 npm lib modules which I am also developing. The webapp and 2 lib modules are  each located in separate git repositories.

I would like to know how i can configure the webpack/dev-server to be able to hot reload changes to the webapp or lib modules without building the modules and then running npm install on the webapp.

The setup would be similar to how eclipse m2e allows war projects to reload jar dependencies without building the jar or war projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add aliases for your packages in the webpack config and point to project paths.